# Gerenciador de banco de dados (Postgres - Linux)

Tags: linux

Alguém conhece um bom gerenciador de banco de dados FREE para Postgres no linux?

Utilizava o EMS SQL Manager para windows. Contudo o mesmo não funcionava para o linux. No momento estou utilizando o Navicat, porém a licença expira em 14 dias :(

Já tentei o pgAdmin, mas o auto-complete funciona quando quer! :S

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual versão do pgAdmin você testou?

Comment: Dei uma olhada e encontrei um gerenciador web para postgresql, se achar interessante de uma olhada aqui -> http://www.planetaunix.com.br/2015/01/neste-artigo-vamos-mostrar-instalacao.html

Comment: Testei a versão 3 do pgAdmin

Comment: Tente a versão `pgAdmin4` é a que uso e o erro descrito não ocorre para mim

Comment: Consegui achar um editor bom após algumas tentativas frustadas... Se chama DBeaver... https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/